# Simple Delete in Entity Framework using WCF (many to many relationship)

Tags: wcf, entity-framework

I have a simple database model containing 3 Tables : **Companies**, **Categories** and **CompanyCategories** (which is a relation table with only 2 FK : CompanyID and CategoryID).

My edmx model it only shows Companies and Categories tables (CompanyCategories is somehow hidded since its a simple many to many relationship table).

In the WCF service, I have a GetDatabase() function that returns all the database objets wrapped in one big custom object :

```
[OperationContract]
public FullDatabase GetDatabase()
{
   DBEntities context = new DBEntities ();

   FullDatabase mydb = new FullDatabase();
   mydb.Companies = context.Companies.ToList();
   mydb.Categories = context.Categories.ToList();

   return mydb;
}

[OperationContract]
public FullDatabase UpdateDatabase(FullDatabase db)
{
    // Here is my problem when removing a category from a company on 
    // the client its been brought back in my db object 
}

class FullDatabase()
{
   List<Company> Companies;
   List<Category> Categories;
}
```

On the client now, I use GetDatabaseAsync() to retrieve the database in a _FullDB variable.  Now using that variable I tried the following :

```
  // Adding a category like that Works well
  Company c = _FullDB.Companies.First();
  c.Categories.Add(_FullDB.Categories.First());
  wcfServiceClientObject.UpdateDatabaseASync(_FullDB);

  .....

  // Removing a category, doesn't work though :
  Company c = _FullDB.Companies.First();
  c.Categories.Remove(_FullDB.Categories.First());
  wcfServiceClientObject.UpdateDatabaseASync(_FullDB);

    // here my c.Categories.Count is updated correctly to delete the item
    // but when on the server after (in the UpdateDatabase function) the item 
    // I deleted is still there
```

I really dont understand why the Add would work but not the Remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the problem. Now it works, but I'm not sure it is the best way to do it.

When removing the category from the company, I also had to also remove the company from the category...

```
Company comp = _FullDB.Companies.First();
Category cat = _FullDB.Categories.First();

comp.Categories.Remove(cat);
cat.Companies.Remove(comp);

wcfServiceClientObject.UpdateDatabaseASync(_FullDB);
```